Multiplicative cancellation for trivial vector bundles
Let $X$ be a scheme, ${\mathscr L}$ an invertible ${\mathscr O}_X$-module, and $d$ a positive integer. If ${\mathscr L}^{\oplus d} \simeq {\mathscr O}_X^{\oplus d}$, does it follow that ${\mathscr L} \simeq {\mathscr O}_X$?
(I am most interested in the case when $X$ is completely arbitrary, though special cases are also welcome. Apologies if this is trivial for some reason that eludes me.)

Let $X$ be a smooth affine curve and $L$ a non- trivial two torsion line bundle. Then $L\oplus L$ is trivial.

No, this is false.
Let $X = Spec(O_F)$ for the ring of integers in a finite extension $F$ of $\Bbb Q$. Then invertible $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules are isomorphic to fractional ideals, and there is always an isomorphism:
$$I \oplus J \cong (I \otimes J) \oplus \mathcal{O}_X$$
Thus, in this case, this question reduces to: given an element $a$ in the ideal class group $Cl(F)$ such that $d \cdot a = 0$ in $Cl(F)$ for some $d > 0$, do we have $a = 0$ in $Cl(F)$? This is false---in fact, all elements in the ideal class group are torsion, and so satisfy this identity for some $d > 0$.

Since I had “forgotten” why the isomorphism $I⊕J\cong(I⊗J)⊕O_F$ holds, here is a reference: Keith Conrad, “Ideal classes and relative integers”, lemma 8.

@Gro-Tsen Thank you! That's definitely not a trivial step.

Adding another reference, to put this in the context of the $K_0$ (Grothendieck group) of algebraic K-theory: Milnor, Introduction to algebraic K-theory (Princeton University Press 1971), theorem 1.6 on p. 11 (this being attributed to Steinitz), or just lemma 1.7 it uses. See also, Ausoni, “An Introduction to Algebraic K-theory”, theorem on p. 2.
